# Does $A\cong B \implies A^*\cong B^*$ hold.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ two vector space. Suppose $A\cong B$. Does $A^*\cong B^*$ ? I recall that $C^*=Hom(C,\mathbb R)$ is the dual of $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $L \colon A \rightarrow B$ is an isomorphism between $A$ and $B$ then $L^{*} \colon B^{*} \rightarrow A^{*}$ given by $L^{*}(\varphi) = \varphi \circ L$ is an isomorphism between $B^{*}$ and $A^{*}$ (its inverse is $(L^{-1})^{*})$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Suppose that $T$ is an isomorphism from $A$ to $B$. Then $T^*$, defined by 
$$
T^* : B^* \to A^*: f \mapsto f \circ T
$$
is an isomorphism.