# Does $U^*\cong V^*$ imply $U\cong V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

> Let $U,V$ be two infinite dimensional spaces over field $k$, **does
> $U^*\cong V^*$ imply $U\cong V$?**

---

The other direction of the question is trivial and can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551553/does-a-cong-b-implies-a-cong-b-hold).

Since $U\hookrightarrow U^{**}$ and $U^{**}\cong V^{**}$, one can treat both $U$ and $V$ as subspaces of $U^{**}$.
I have no idea what to do next?

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/750106/122262

Comment: If you can find the Hamel dimension formula for $\dim (U^*)$ in terms of $\dim U$, then this becomes a question about cardinal arithmetic.  Note, for the corresponding question about Banach spaces with linear homeomorphism: the answer is "no".